# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Long to String

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i am trying to fetch the data from firebase databse. i am using FirebaseDatabase. while fetching the data i am getting above exception. there is no long variable in firebase and local. i am getting proper data.

```
DatabaseReference firebase = Firebase.getInstance().getReference().child(FirebaseConfig.PRODUCT_MASTER);
        Query query = firebase.orderByChild(getString(R.string.COLUMN_RETAILER_ID)).equalTo(retailerId);
        query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Product_Master productMaster = dataSnapshot.getValue(Product_Master.class);
                pdtMasterList.add(productMaster);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot,
```

String s) {

```
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }


        });
```

```
public class Product_Master {

    @SerializedName("brand")
    private String brand;

    @SerializedName("category")
    private String category;

    @SerializedName("display_name")
    private String display_name;

    @SerializedName("dealer_price")
    private String dealer_price;

    @SerializedName("distributor_id")
    private String distributor_id;

    @SerializedName("EAN")
    private String EAN;

    @SerializedName("image")
    private String image;

    @SerializedName("image_folder")
    private String image_folder;

    @SerializedName("item_description1")
    private String item_description1;

    @SerializedName("item_description2")
    private String item_description2;

    @SerializedName("item_id")
    private String item_id;

    @SerializedName("loose_category")
    private String loose_category;

    @SerializedName("description")
    private String description;

    @SerializedName("major_category")
    private String major_category;

    @SerializedName("moq")
    private String moq;

    @SerializedName("sub_category")
    private String sub_category;

    @SerializedName("varaiety")
    private String varaiety;

    @SerializedName("vat_percent")
    private String vat_percent;

    @SerializedName("type_product")
    private String type_product;

    @SerializedName("weight")
    private String weight;

    @SerializedName("offer_price")
    private String offer_price;

    @SerializedName("offer_indicator")
    private String offer_indicator;

    @SerializedName("mov")
    private String mov;

    @SerializedName("retailer_id")
    private String retailer_id;

    @SerializedName("retailer_price")
    private String retailer_price;

    @SerializedName("market_price")
    private String market_price;

    @SerializedName("price")
    private ArrayList<Price> price;

    public String getMov() {
        return mov;
    }

    public void setMov(String mov) {
        this.mov = mov;
    }

    public String getRetailer_price() {
        return retailer_price;
    }

    public void setRetailer_price(String retailer_price) {
        this.retailer_price = retailer_price;
    }

    public String getOffer_price() {
        return offer_price;
    }

    public void setOffer_price(String offer_price) {
        this.offer_price = offer_price;
    }

    public String getOffer_indicator() {
        return offer_indicator;
    }

    public void setOffer_indicator(String offer_indicator) {
        this.offer_indicator = offer_indicator;
    }

    public Product_Master() {
    }

    public String getDealer_price() {
        return dealer_price;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getImage_folder() {
        return image_folder;
    }

    public void setImage_folder(String image_folder) {
        this.image_folder = image_folder;
    }

    public void setDealer_price(String dealer_price) {
        this.dealer_price = dealer_price;
    }

    public String getDisplay_name() {
        return display_name;
    }

    public void setDisplay_name(String display_name) {
        this.display_name = display_name;
    }

    public String getDistributor_id() {
        return distributor_id;
    }

    public void setDistributor_id(String distributor_id) {
        this.distributor_id = distributor_id;
    }

    public String getMoq() {
        return moq;
    }

    public void setMoq(String moq) {
        this.moq = moq;
    }

    public String getRetailer_id() {
        return retailer_id;
    }

    public String getMarket_price() {
        return market_price;
    }

    public void setMarket_price(String market_price) {
        this.market_price = market_price;
    }

    public void setRetailer_id(String retailer_id) {
        this.retailer_id = retailer_id;
    }

    public String getItem_id() {
        return item_id;
    }

    public void setItem_id(String item_id) {
        this.item_id = item_id;
    }

    public String getItem_description1() {
        return item_description1;
    }

    public void setItem_description1(String item_description1) {
        this.item_description1 = item_description1;
    }

    public String getItem_description2() {
        return item_description2;
    }

    public void setItem_description2(String item_description2) {
        this.item_description2 = item_description2;
    }

    public String getMajor_category() {
        return major_category;
    }

    public void setMajor_category(String major_category) {
        this.major_category = major_category;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getSub_category() {
        return sub_category;
    }

    public void setSub_category(String sub_category) {
        this.sub_category = sub_category;
    }

    public String getVaraiety() {
        return varaiety;
    }

    public void setVaraiety(String varaiety) {
        this.varaiety = varaiety;
    }

    public String getLoose_category() {
        return loose_category;
    }

    public void setLoose_category(String loose_category) {
        this.loose_category = loose_category;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getEAN() {
        return EAN;
    }

    public void setEAN(String EAN) {
        this.EAN = EAN;
    }

    public String getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }

    public void setBrand(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    public String getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(String weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public String getVat_percent() {
        return vat_percent;
    }

    public void setVat_percent(String vat_percent) {
        this.vat_percent = vat_percent;
    }

    public String getType_product() {
        return type_product;
    }

    public void setType_product(String type_product) {
        this.type_product = type_product;
    }

    public ArrayList<Price> getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(ArrayList<Price> price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public static class Price
    {

        private String weight;
        private String offer_price;
        private String dealer_price;

        public Price(String weight, String offer_price, String dealer_price) {
            this.weight = weight;
            this.offer_price = offer_price;
            this.dealer_price = dealer_price;
        }

        public String getWeight() {
            return weight;
        }

        public void setWeight(String weight) {
            this.weight = weight;
        }

        public String getOffer_price() {
            return offer_price;
        }

        public void setOffer_price(String offer_price) {
            this.offer_price = offer_price;
        }

        public String getDealer_price() {
            return dealer_price;
        }

        public void setDealer_price(String dealer_price) {
            this.dealer_price = dealer_price;
        }
    }
}
```

```
{
  "brand" : "GTS Bullet",
  "category" : "RICE",
  "dealer_price" : "1000",
  "description" : "Sona Masuri - A1 Quality - 25Kg",
  "display_name" : "SuperZop Traders",
  "distributor_id" : "1001",
  "ean" : "",
  "image" : "sona_masuri_rice_large.jpg",
  "image_folder" : "superzop_ordering_product_images",
  "item_description1" : "Sona Masuri",
  "item_description2" : "A1 Quality",
  "item_id" : "100001",
  "loose_category" : "RICE",
  "major_category" : "GROCERY",
  "market_price" : "",
  "moq" : "50Kg",
  "mov" : "5000",
  "offer_indicator" : "",
  "offer_price" : "800",
  "retailer_id" : 10001,
  "sub_category" : "RICE",
  "type_product" : "MRP",
  "varaiety" : "",
  "vat_percent" : "12.50%",
  "weight" : "25Kg"
}
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code.

Comment: i have added the code please check @AndréKool

Comment: Can you also add (a sample of) your data in firebase? As text please, not as image.

Comment: added please check @AndréKool

Comment: The problem is "retailer_id" : 10001, in your database it is a number but in your code you say it's a string.

Comment: Thank you very much . i missed that. @AndréKool